# Thumbnails and original image on the same page

Tags: html, image, optimization, thumbnails, image-resizing

On my site I have a featured image/content slider which shows a set of larger images (~100kb) with thumbnails underneath (~10kb each). The question is fairly simple - should I use a browser side resize of the larger image or download the thumbnails? Each seems to have a downside; the processor impact on the browser (particularly important on mobile devices) or the additional downloads caused by downloading the thumbnails.

So, what is the common advice?

Answer (score 2):

I would use on the fly **server side** resized images for the thumbnails and cache them so I don't have to resize them again. Here are a few reasons I would do that:

1. Server side images do not add extra javascript to your pages which in turn adds extra load time.
2. Server side images can be cached easily with the right headers. Caching client side resized images could prove to be an issue in some browsers and may cause wasteful re-sizing each time the page is loaded.
3. Client side image sizing speed will be effected by browser and computer/device speed and current work load.
4. In the client side solution the user must download the high res images first in order to then resize. With the images ready server side you are tapping into most modern browsers ability to parallelize downloads even more since they allow X amount of concurrent connections to take place. You can see a list of connections per hostname allowed for each browser on [browserscope](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network&v=top).
5. Some browsers will not support the resize method you go with and you may have to find work-arounds or polyfills to support some browsers. For example going Canvas route.
6. If your content slider grew to lets say a total of 16 images, you may need to incorporate some slide pagination. If not done correctly you would be forcing clients to generate images they perhaps don't even care to see. This would make the [User's perception](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/usability-latency) that your page is not finished loading and feel slow. In that case I would want to not even load the images and thumbnails that are hidden or off screen until the user clicks next page in the paginated slider. Similar in technique to what the [lazy loading plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) does.
7. Server side images can be loaded from a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network). Client side images cannot.

P.s. There are tons of server side image resizing solutions out there that are very fast. [Jpegtran](http://jpegclub.org/jpegtran/) is just one pretty good one that's a simple command line tool and you will find it already available on most linux distros. If you are looking for somethong more robust I would also recommend [graphicsmagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) and it's many ports to various languages like [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmagick.php)

Answer (score 0):

That depends.
How many resizing should a single user should experience? If the number is fairly small than I would consider doing that on the client side in order to distribute the workload.

If the number is quite high than obviously I'd rather do that on the server side.
This approach requires you servers to be able to provide the required performance.

Comment: The images are already re-sized (I use wordpress which does the resizing on upload). Therefore it comes down to the browser performance verses the speed impact of the additional downloads.

At the moment, I only have 4 images cycling through the slider, therefore only 4 thumbnails